# ClassNotFound exception wildfly 27

Tags: java, runtime, wildfly, classnotfoundexception

practically for me the servlet is not working , first using WildFly 10 it gave me an error not having the jre 1.8 I downloaded it but then it gave me another error saying that the class was compiled with a runtime version 63.0 and was not supported , I so I checked which version of Java supported 63 and it came out that it was 19 , I installed etc. I also decided to use wildfly 27 , I started the server but now it no longer gives me the version error but rather tells me that can't find the class

I also tried to use a new project but nothing

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: finally fixed itself last night maybe needed a cleanup of eclipse

Answer (score 1):

WildFly 27 is JakartaEE 10, given your lopps I think you are using JavaEE 7/_ code.
You an specify the tzrget version of your code when you compile it if you really need it to be Java 8 compatible.

Comment: which is your advice?

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve.  WildFly no longer support Java EE 7/8 so in the long term  you will have to migrate to JakartaEE 10 or more. It all depends on your schedule and available time. Note that WildFly 10 is very very old and is not supported since only the latest version is.